# Symfony autorun function

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I built a login system in Symfony. On every page that *is secured* I need to validate that the username matches the password. I wrote a function: `isValidAuth()` in **myUser.class.php**. Nevertheless I need to write these lines in actions for every page:

```
if(!isValidAuth())
{
    $this->forward('home', 'logout');
}
```

which is quite inconvenient when you have multiple pages and modules that are secured. Is there any way I can run these lines like a function if the page `is_secured`? Like when accessing `executeIndex()` at page load?

Comment: besides me answer. there a few other way's to achieve such "autorun"-functionality. for example you could extend sfAction with your custom constructor or use the `preExecute()` and `postExecute()` functions witch will be executed everytime you call an action of your module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for this would be the filterchain, I'd even suggest extending sfBasicSecurityFilter. To enable your extended class, edit apps/myapp/config/filters.yml

```
rendering: ~
security:
  class: myExtendedSecurityFilter

# Generally, you will want to insert your own filters here

cache:     ~
execution: ~
```

Instead of extending the sfBasicSecurityFilter, you could also create a new class that extends sfFilter. Read more about filters here:

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters

Answer (score 1):

There is a build in feature in Symfony which handle this. The manaual is for version 1.2 but it should also work for version 1.4: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer.

since the config values in 1.4 have changed to true/false instead of on/off, you will have to change them: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/08-Security

apps/frontend/modules/mymodule/config/security.yml

```
all:
  is_secure:   true       # for all actions of a module

foo:
  is_secure:   false       # action foo is public
```

in  apps/frontend/config/settings.yml you will have to provide a module and action which does the login etc.

```
all:
  .actions:
    login_module:  default
    login_action:  login

    secure_module: default
    secure_action: secure
```

And last but not least you need to setAuthenticated Flag on your User (usualy after the login ;) ):

```
$this->getUser()->setAuthenticated(true);
```

by the way. maybe you should install the sfdoctrineguardplugin which provides the user handling, login etc out of the box ;)